# OnSubmit Calls a function that invokes 3 function and checks return_type, but 1 function is not getting invoked

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, bootstrap-4

1. Form that takes values from user, OnSubmit calls function check_three_func()

```
<form method="post" action="register_action.php" id="register_form" name="register_form"
 onsubmit="return check_three_func()">
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uname">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Enter Name " name="uname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uemail">Email id: </label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="uemail" placeholder="Enter Email ID" name="uemail">
    <!-- onkeyup="javascript:validate(this.value)" -->
    <span id="alert" style="display:none"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="upassword">Enter Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="upassword" placeholder="Set password" name="upassword">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ucpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ucpassword" placeholder="Enter password again" name="ucpassword" >
  </div>
  <!-- captcha div -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <img src="captcha.php" class="rounded" alt="Captcha"><br>
    <label for="captcha">Enter Captcha: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha"  name="captcha" maxlength="6">
     <!-- onkeyup="javascript:captcha_func(this.value)" -->
     <span id="captcha-result" style="display:none"></span>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-button" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

2. check_three_func() calls 3 functions mention below in code and returns the return_type so if false then it wont be able to submit the form

```
function check_three_func(){
    var check_email_func=check_email();
    var click_to_func=click_to();
    var check_func=check();
    if( check_email_func==true && click_to_func==true && check_func==true){
      return true;
      console.log("all true");
    }
    else{
      return false;
      console.log(" false");
    }
}
```

3.check_email() is not getting invoke OnSubmit

```
function check_email(){
  var email = document.getElementById("uemail").value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("alert").style.display="inline";
      if(xhttp.responseText=="EMP"){
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>fill out emai id</span>";
        console.log("Email id empty return false");
        return false;
      }
      else if(xhttp.responseText=="OK"){
      document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-success' >welcome new user</span>";
      //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
      console.log("New email id return true");
      return true;
      }
      else if(xhttp.responseText=="NO"){
      document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>Email Already Exist</span>";
      //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
      console.log("Email id already exsist return false");
      return false;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
        //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
        console.log("Error fetching email id");
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET","emailvalidate.php?uemail="+email,true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

4. While Function click_to() and check() are invoked and giving the desired validation

```
function click_to(){
  var code = document.getElementById("captcha").value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("captcha-result").style.display="inline";
    if(xhttp.responseText=="EMP"){
      document.getElementById("captcha-result").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Cannot be Kept Empty</span>";
      //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
      console.log("Cannot be empty return false");
      return false;
    }
    else if(xhttp.responseText=="INVALID"){
      document.getElementById("captcha-result").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>Invalid Captcha code</span>";
      //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
      console.log("Invalid code return false");
      return false;
    }
    else if(xhttp.responseText=="VALID"){
    document.getElementById("captcha-result").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-success' >Valid Captcha code</span>";
    //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
    console.log("valid code return true");
    return true;
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("captcha-result").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    //  document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
    console.log("Error return false");
      return false;
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET","submited_captcha.php?captcha="+code,true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

5. Check() function code below

```
function check(){
    var uname=document.forms["register_form"]["uname"].value;
    var uemail=document.forms["register_form"]["uemail"].value;
    var upassword=document.forms["register_form"]["upassword"].value;
    var ucpassword=document.forms["register_form"]["ucpassword"].value;
    var captcha=document.forms["register_form"]["captcha"].value;
    var upassword_length=upassword.length;
    if(uname=="" || uemail=="" || upassword=="" || ucpassword=="" || captcha==""){
      alert("all fields must be filled out");
      console.log("all fields must be filled");
      return false;
    }
    else if (upassword.length <= 6 ) {
      alert("Password length should be more than 6 Characters ");
      console.log("pass length not more than 6");
      return false;
    }
    else if(upassword != ucpassword){
      alert("Confirm password should be same as password");
      console.log("pass not matching");
      return false;
    }
    else{
      alert("All fields filled");
      console.log("true all fields filled");
      return true;
    }

  }
```

6.check_email() and click_to() have ajax scripts in it. 
  Below is the php page that the ajax script in chech_email() is calling

```
<?php
$eid=$_GET['uemail'];
if(empty($eid)){
  echo "EMP";
}
else{
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_pagination");
if(!$conn){
  die("connection error".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql="select email_id from user where email_id='$eid' ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(!$result){
  echo "error:".mysqli_error($conn);
}
$row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row==0){
  echo "OK";  
}
if($row > 0){
  echo "NO";
}

}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update async parameter value to false. If async parameter value is false, the send() method does not return until the response is received.

```
xhttp.open("GET","emailvalidate.php?uemail="+email,false);
```

Try below code it will work.

```
function check_email(){
  var email = document.getElementById("uemail").value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
 else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  result = true; // create a variable result and by default make it true.
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("alert").style.display="inline";
      if(xhttp.responseText=="EMP"){
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>fill out emai id</span>";
        console.log("Email id empty return false");
        result = false;
      }
      else if(xhttp.responseText=="OK"){
      document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-success' >welcome new user</span>";
      //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
      console.log("New email id return true");
      }
      else if(xhttp.responseText=="NO"){
      document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>Email Already Exist</span>";
      //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
      console.log("Email id already exsist return false");
      result = false;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
        //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
        console.log("Error fetching email id");
        result = false;
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET","emailvalidate.php?uemail="+email,false);
  xhttp.send();

  return result;  //at last return the result.
}
```

Comment: I only changed true to false and it worked - xhttp.open("GET","emailvalidate.php?uemail="+email,false);

Comment: just a question in click_to() function i have this line of code- xhttp.open("GET","submited_captcha.php?captcha="+code,true); but still its working why so? and why did'nt it work with check_email()?

Comment: Maybe check_email() taking time to get the response. And before getting the response from check_email other two function got executed.

Comment: yes u may be right as click_to() is only comparing a value in variable with a session variable and check_email() is firing a query and checking the results if matched

Comment: now there is one more problem the check_three_func() all 3 variables are returning false why so even if i am using return true;

Comment: Please debug the function using console or alert, maybe some issue while returning the result.

Comment: it says undefined on both return true and return false;

Comment: In each function create a variable like result and make it true by default. based on condition assign the the value (true/false) in that variable. at last return variable in function. Check me my code. maybe it will help.

Comment: did as u said it worked thanks for the help buddy. I am new to web development any tips to improve my knowledge. Do I need to improve my code readability or logic of code?

Comment: The code you mention in question is fine. Initially you can learn, JavaScript, jQuery, CSS, HTML. After that lot's of framework are there for web development like Angular, react js, Node Js etc need to focus on that. you can take the help of google there are lot's of good site to learn web technologies.

Answer (score 0):

The `check_email` is an async function. That's why you are not getting the return result. you have to call the function like below.

Add the async  before the `function` keyword and add await keyword before the `check_email` `function`.

```
async function check_three_func() {
    var check_email_func = await check_email();
    var click_to_func = click_to();
    var check_func = check();
    if (check_email_func && click_to_func && check_func) {
        return true;
        console.log("all true");
    }
    else {
        return false;
        console.log(" false");
    }
}
```

2. Wrappe your ajax code in a promise and resolve or reject based on the response and then return that promise.

```
function check_email() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var email = document.getElementById("uemail").value;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "inline";
                if (xhttp.responseText == "EMP") {
                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-info'>fill out emai id</span>";
                    console.log("Email id empty return false");
                    reject(false);
                }
                else if (xhttp.responseText == "OK") {
                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-success' >welcome new user</span>";
                    //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
                    console.log("New email id return true");
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else if (xhttp.responseText == "NO") {
                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = "<br><span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>Email Already Exist</span>";
                    //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
                    console.log("Email id already exsist return false");
                    reject(false);
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    //document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
                    console.log("Error fetching email id");
                    reject(false);
                }
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "emailvalidate.php?uemail=" + email, true);
        xhttp.send();
    });

}
```

Comment: so how click_to() is giving me the desired output? As check_email() and click_to() have same type of code structure

Comment: As the `click_to` is also a async function and in your current code it is returning undefined which is a falsy value. The `click_to` executes and return immediately, but the ajax call is an async call and it will execute later.

Comment: You can console.log the `click_to_func` and see the value in the console.

Comment: Sorry to say the above code did'nt work. When I submitted the form with blank inputs it used to submit the form with blank values.